# make: how to save failure code of a prior command and then later return that failure code?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

## Problem

Given a make rule that should return the failure code from a sandwiched middle command, how do I save and then return that failure code?
Specifically, given a `make` target like

```
 mytarget:
    do some necessary beginning for all targets that must occur for every run of this Makefile
    -$(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS)
    do some necessary ending for all targets that must occur for every run of this Makefile

 # more targets follow
```

How to have `make` exit with the return code of the `-$(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS)` command?
That is, how to

```
 mytarget:
    do some necessary beginning for all targets that must occur for every run of this Makefile
    -$(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS)
    return_code=$?  # psuedo-code
    do some necessary ending for all targets that must occur for every run of this Makefile
    exit $(return_code)
```

This needs to occur without the `--ignore-errors` option.

## Update

@EugeniuRosca provided a perfectly reasonable answer, "*Your return_code=$? line must be executed in the SAME subshell with the previous shell command*".

However, I was hoping for an answer that used native make capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return_code=$?` line must be executed in the *SAME* subshell with the previous shell command `-$(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS)`, like this:

```
mytarget:
    # intro actions
    -make whatever; \
        return_code=$$?; \
        # end actions; \
        exit $$return_code
```

If you execute the `#end ections` on a separate row of the recipe without using `\`, the `$?` value is simply lost when the subshell terminates.

Comment: You have the right idea but you've forgotten to escape the shell variables; both `$?` (should be `$$?` here) and `$return_code` (should be `$$return_code`, without parentheses) are _shell_ variables not make variables.  Although, I don't really see the point in going to all this trouble to return the exit code and then use `-` as a recipe line prefix, which ignores exit codes...

Comment: @MadScientist you are right about escaping the non-makefile variables! I just skipped the smoke test on my machine, which is always a mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca , I was hoping this would be done without including all calls in one large sub-shell process.  Each step would be an independent `make` command.  I suspect your answer  "_Your return_code=$? line must be executed in the SAME subshell with the previous shell command_" will have to suffice.  I was just hoping `make` had this capability natively.  Thanks!